# Windows 10 Creators Update pin to start strange result

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, windows-10-v1703

My start menu worked perfectly fine, until the Windows 10 Creators Update. I now don't have any of my own applications (such as CCleaner, but also administrative tools), but just the windows apps in the *All Apps* list (such as Calculator, Calendar).

I have already tried:

- replacing the TileDataLayer folder
- modifying indexing settings
- adding new shortcuts to the Start Menu folder (*C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs*)
- creating new user accounts (there as well it didn't work)

But to no avail...

On top of that, when I choose the option to "Pin to Start", this is the result:

[image: Strange Pin to Start result]

As a temporary work-around for myself, I added a new toolbar to the taskbar of the *C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs* folder, but this of course is not very convenient.

**Edit**

After re-upgrading to the creators update again (no rollback), the problem persists for all user accounts (even newly created ones, as well normal as Administrator). *However*, the built-in Administrator account works perfectly fine. I copied the TileDataLayer folder from the Admin to my account, even with changes permissions, but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: You should rollback to 1607 then reinstall the update

Comment: unfortunately I deleted them, I know.. not very thoughtful of me

Comment: I have the same issue with games in the Windows "Games" list only, while all other tiles are working (e.g. LibreOffice, Firefox, Chrome, Sketchup, Audacity). Rollback and update did not fix the issue, nor did DISM.

Comment: I don't think it's a coincidence these are games - I've had the same issue with some "Games for Windows" games from 2009 which had tight Windows Vista Games Explorer integration, I wonder if Microsoft had some kind of Games Explorer integration in Windows 10 planned but never followed-through...

Answer (score 1):

*Source: http://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-dism-command-line-utility-repair-windows-10-image*

Roll-back and re-update may be a good solution, but personally I'd try repairing the Windows Image first using the DISM commands.

1. Open an elevated Command Prompt by right-clicking on your Start Menu and selecting **Command Prompt (admin)** *Note: Depending on your settings, you may open Windows Powershell (Admin)*
2. Type `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Wait for this to complete
4. Type `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. Wait for this to complete

Together these scan and identify errors in your Windows image and then repair them.

I'd only suggest running these before trying a roll-back and re-update because together they should take less time than the roll-back option.

However, if the issue persists, then try rolling back:

1. Open **Settings**, **Updates and Security**, and **Recovery**
2. Under **Go back to the previous version of Windows 10** click **Get started**
3. Follow the instructions.

Comment: I tried both DISM commands, but it kept telling me that it couldn't find a source, even if I mentioned the install.esd file from the creators update. I then re-upgraded to the creators update, keeping files but not apps and settings, and now the problem persists, even with new user accounts created. However, the built-in admin account works perfectly fine! See my edit for more info

Comment: @user2606722 - You will have to manually mount the .wim from a 1703 ISO, then direct DISM to use that source, since the source on your installation is missing or corrupt.

Comment: @Ramhound the dism source files still failed, with the latest iso from the Microsoft website